# Find the cumulative distribution function.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

$f(x)=20 x (1-x)^3$ over $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

I know that by definition the cumulative distribution function if $F(x) = P(X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt$. In this case, I must have $F(x) = \int_a^b 20t(1-t)^3\,dt$ but what must $a$ and $b$ be in this case?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $0\le x\le 1$ then
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^0 0\,dt + \int_0^x 20t(1-t)^3\,dt = \int_0^x 20t(1-t)^3\,dt.
$$

Comment: Thank you Michael. So I now have $F(x) = -5x(1-x)^4 - (1-x)^5 + 1$. Then I believe $P(X < 1/2) = F(1/2)$. How can I use $f(x) = 20x(1-x)^3$ to find $P(X < 1/2)$?

Comment: Never mind Michael. I think I got it. Thanks so much for your help!